# How to scrape weight of player which is a hidden content using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hidden, innertext

I have been trying to get the weight of this player, but it is only visible on the inspect element and not on the website, when I print the below, I get a blank result, Could anyone please help me with this?

Code trials:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s = Service('/Users/karim/Desktop/chromedriver-2')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
url = 'https://www.premierleague.com/players/71432/Rayan-A%C3%AFt-Nouri/overview'
driver.get(url)

g = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='u-hide']")
print(g.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

1. Click on accept cookies button.
2. Click on the close button that is on the top right-hand side.

**Code:**

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://www.premierleague.com/players/71432/Rayan-A%C3%AFt-Nouri/overview")

try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept All Cookies']"))).click()
    print("clicked on accept cookies button")
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#advertClose"))).click()
except:
    pass

#print(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='u-hide']"))).get_attribute('innerText'))
print(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='u-hide']//div[@class='info']"))).get_attribute('innerText'))
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output:**

```
clicked on accept cookies button
70kg

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: What was the reason, can you explain a bit more ? I applied the same cookies action but that did not solve it. How did you come up with the advert solution, it's not even showing up on the page. Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: When you try to get the weight from the web page manually, you will have to do this `1. Click on accept cookies button.
2. Click on the close button that is on the top right-hand side.` and then use the `get_attribute('innerText')` on the web element.

Comment: I didn't need to do anything of sort in order to get the weight manually from the page. I don't see any ad either, tried closing adblockers and all but to no avail. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

The weight of the player is within:

```
<div class="info">70kg</div>
```

which is within it's ancestor:

```
<li class="u-hide">
          <div class="label">Weight</div>
          <div class="info">70kg</div>
    </li>
```

where the *`<li>`* is having *class* as *`u-hide`*

As the element is a ***hidden*** element using *`text`* attribute won't work here and you have extract either the *`innerHTML`* or the *`innerText`*.

---

### Solution

To print the value of the *Weight* you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *`innerHTML`*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='u-hide']//div[@class='info']").get_attribute('innerHTML'))
  ```
- Using *`innerText`*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='u-hide']//div[@class='info']").get_attribute('innerText'))
  ```

Inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447):

- Using *`innerHTML`*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='u-hide']//div[@class='info']"))).get_attribute('innerHTML'))
  ```
- Using *`innerText`*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='u-hide']//div[@class='info']"))).get_attribute('innerText'))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  70kg
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```